# Determine a specific fortnight based on anchor dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 x bi-weekly periods that were defined by 2 starting dates 1 week apart. For example, Group 1 started on `2016-01-15` and Group 2 started on `2016-01-22`.

By bi-weekly, I mean a rolling period lasting 2 weeks.

How can I determine if the current date is in week 1 of Group 1 or is in week 1 of Group 2?

By way of example, today's date is `2016-04-04` so this would be day 1 of Group 2 and day 8 of Group 1, therefore I would like to a query to return 'Group 2'.

Comment: Please elaborate on your question.  The current date is in April and by my definition of bi-weekly is in neither period, both of which ended in January or February.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DATEDIFF` calculates the difference between two dates. Divide it by 14 days and take the remainder (`%`).

If remainder is less than 7, then it is closer to that starting date.

Since you know that your starting dates are 1 week apart you really need to check only one starting date.

```
DECLARE @VarStartGroup1 date = '2016-01-15';
DECLARE @VarStartGroup2 date = '2016-01-22';
DECLARE @VarCurrentDate date = '2016-04-04';

SELECT
    DATEDIFF(day, @VarStartGroup1, @VarCurrentDate) AS TotalDays1,
    DATEDIFF(day, @VarStartGroup2, @VarCurrentDate) AS TotalDays2,
    DATEDIFF(day, @VarStartGroup1, @VarCurrentDate) % 14 AS DayNumberInGroup1,
    DATEDIFF(day, @VarStartGroup2, @VarCurrentDate) % 14 AS DayNumberInGroup2,
    CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, @VarStartGroup1, @VarCurrentDate) % 14 < 7
    THEN 'Group1' ELSE 'Group2' END AS Result
;
```

**Result**

```
+------------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------+
| TotalDays1 | TotalDays2 | DayNumberInGroup1 | DayNumberInGroup2 | Result |
+------------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------+
|         80 |         73 |                10 |                 3 | Group2 |
+------------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------+
```

I included intermediate calculations in the result to help understand what is going on.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you.